# MySQL query - IF statement to generate two different rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have some issues with below script, essentially what I'm trying to achieve is to grab different product and prices and generate a table which works fine. However, some of the products do have an extra charge, in this case the product will use three rows (price, extra charge and total sum). I'm trying to get the IF statement to work as follows: if the extra charge = 0 then it should only make a single row in the table, if more then 0 it should produce the 3 row version.

Someone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
$page=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); /* Returns PHP File Name */
$page_name=str_replace(".php","",$page);
mysql_connect(localhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query= ("SELECT * FROM table e 
            JOIN validdate1 r ON e.datevalid1=r.id 
            JOIN validdate2 d ON e.datevalid2=d.id 
         WHERE productpage='$page_name' 
            ORDER BY productname,price2");

       $result=mysql_query($query);

       $num=mysql_numrows($result);
       mysql_close();?>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="headerdesc">Description</th>
        <th class="headerprice1 rates1">2015</th>
        <th class="headerprice2 rates2">2016</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<?php $i=0;while ($i < $num)
{
  $productname = mysql_result($result,$i,"productname");
  $price1=mysql_result($result,$i,"price1");
  $price2=mysql_result($result,$i,"price2");
  $extracharge1=mysql_result($result,$i,"extracharge1");
  $extracharge2=mysql_result($result,$i,"extracharge2");
  $daterange1=mysql_result($result,$i,"daterange1");
  $daterange2=mysql_result($result,$i,"daterange2");

if ($extracharge1 > "0") {
echo "  <tr>
    <td class="desc"><?php echo $productname; ?></td>
    <td class="price1 rates1">$<? echo $price1; ?></td>
    <td class="price2 rates2">$<? echo $price2; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="extra">Extra Charge**</td>
    <td class="price1 rates1">$<? echo $extracharge1; ?></td>
    <td class="price2 rates2">$<? echo $extracharge2; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr class="lastrow">
    <td class="totalprice"><strong>Total price</strong></td>
    <td class="total rates1"><strong>$<? echo $price1+$extracharge1; ?></strong></td>
    <td class="total rates2"><strong>$<? echo $price2+$extracharge2; ?></strong></td>
</tr>";
} else {
echo "  <tr class="lastrow">
    <td class="extra"><?php echo $productname; ?></td>
    <td class="price1 rates1">$<? echo $price1; ?></td>
    <td class="price2 rates2">$<? echo $price2; ?></td>
</tr>";
}
?>
<?php $i++;}?>
</table>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several error in code, change it like this, on the top below query

```
$num=mysql_numrows($result); will be 
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

don't close the connection since you are still performing queries below

```
//mysql_close(); comment it out and move it to bottom
```

and here you need this

```
if (mysql_num_rows($extracharge1) > 0 )
```

You are comparing string with a resource in your code

**note:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions its deprecated, use [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) or [mysqli_*](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I couldn't get it to work properly using above, but with below code it seems to work. And when it comes to using mysql_ functions I need to read up on this! Sorry I'm new to MySQL!

Comment: <?php if (mysql_result($result,$i,"extracharge2") > 0 ): ?>